# Issue with registering widget to overwrite legend and map elements: ArcGIS API/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis

I am trying to overcome an issue when trying to display new maps.  The goal of this code is to have the dropdown menu selection overwrite the existing map in the Content pane as well as overwrite the information in the Legend on the tab container.  When running the code, I am running into the following error:

```
Error: Tried to register widget with id==legend1 but that id is already registered
```

I understand that the destroy function I created should delete the code I created previously, but I am unsure as to the origin of the issue.

I was wondering what could be the cause of this issue and how I could get around it? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lab 6 Web API Map selection</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.13.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/esri/css/esri.css">

  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/"></script>
  <script>
    var map, scalebar, legendDijit, overviewMapDijit;
    require([
      "dojo/parser",
      "dijit/form/Select",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
      "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
      "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
      "dojo/on",
      "dojo/dom",
      "dijit/registry",
      "dojo/dom-construct",
      "esri/map",
      "esri/urlUtils",
      "esri/arcgis/utils",
      "esri/dijit/Legend",
      "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
      "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (
      parser,
      select,
      BorderContainer,
      TabContainer,
      ContentPane,
      on,
      dom,
      registry,
      domConstruct,
      Map,
      urlUtils,
      arcgisUtils,
      Legend,
      Scalebar,
      OverviewMap
    ) {   
        parser.parse();

        //Initial map creation for Chicago youth
        arcgisUtils.createMap("c63cdcbbba034b62a2f3becac021b0a8", 
"MapArea").then(function (response) {

            dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
            var map = response.map;

            var scalebar = new Scalebar({
                map: map,
                scalebarUnit: "english"
            });

            var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
            var legendDijit = new Legend({
                map: map,
                layerInfos: legendLayers
                }, "legend1");
                legendDijit.startup();

            var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
                map: map,
                visible: true
            });
            overviewMapDijit.startup();  
        });


        var dropdown = registry.byId("mapoption").attr('value');
        var switch1 = registry.byId("mapoption");
        //function which swtiches between the maps and creates new map aspects 
        //for each new map.
        switch1.on('change', function(event){
            var dropdown = registry.byId('mapoption').attr('value');
            dom.byId('title').innerHTML = dropdown;
            switch (dropdown){

                case "Chicago":
                    destroyerFunc();

                    arcgisUtils.createMap("c63cdcbbba034b62a2f3becac021b0a8", 
                    "MapArea").then(function (response) {

                    dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
                    var map = response.map;

                    var scalebar = new Scalebar({
                        map: map,
                        scalebarUnit: "english"
                    });

                    var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
                    var legendDijit = new Legend({
                        map: map,
                        layerInfos: legendLayers
                      }, "legend1");
                      legendDijit.startup();

                    var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
                      map: map,
                      visible: true
                    });
                    overviewMapDijit.startup();  
                    });
                break;

                case "MedianInc":
                    destroyerFunc();

                    arcgisUtils.createMap("1e79439598494713b553f990a4040886", 
                    "MapArea").then(function (response) {

                    dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
                    var map = response.map;

                    var scalebar = new Scalebar({
                      map: map,
                      scalebarUnit: "english"
                    });

                    var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response);
                    var legendDijit = new Legend({
                        map: map,
                        layerInfos: legendLayers
                      }, "legend1");
                      legendDijit.startup();

                      var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
                      map: map,
                      visible: true
                    });
                    overviewMapDijit.startup();

                    });
                break;

                case "Topographic":             
                    destroyerFunc();

                    map = new Map("MapArea", {
                        basemap: "topo",  
                        center: [-90.34, 47.21], 
                        zoom: 5
                    });

                    var scalebar = new Scalebar({
                        map: map,
                        scalebarUnit: "english"
                    });

                    var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
                        map: map,
                        visible: true
                    });
                    overviewMapDijit.startup();
                    break;
                }
                });

            //function which destroys the elements in the old map while making 
            new ones 
            function destroyerFunc(){
                    var oldLegend = dom.byId("legend1");
                    oldLegend.remove();
                    var legendTab = dom.byId("TabData");
                    var newLegend = document.createElement("div");
                    newLegend.setAttribute("id", "legend1");
                    legendTab.appendChild(newLegend);

                    if (map != undefined) {
                        map.destroy();
                        scalebar.destroy();
                        legendDijit.destroy();
                        overviewMapDijit.destroy();
            }};
        });

  </script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #header {
      background-color: #E8E8E8;
      height: 65px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    #mainWindow {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #title {
      padding-top: 2px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      font-size: 18pt;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    #map {
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 0;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'">
        <div id="header" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
            <div id="title"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
            <div id = 'MapArea' style = "width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="LegendSearch" data-do`enter code here`jo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'left'" style="width:275px; border: 1px solid grey">
            <div id="mapLayers" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Map Selection" >
                <select id = "mapoption" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">    
                    <option value = "Chicago" selected = 'selected'>Chicago Youth Population</option>
                    <option value = "MedianInc">USA Median Household Income </option>
                    <option value = "Topographic"> Topo Map</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="TabData" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Map Legend">
                <div id = "legend1"></div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy the widgets before switching with widget.distroy() and after that you have to destroy div elements also , before closings the function you have to recreate empty div elements so that it will recreate widget. Use dojo construct module to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Declare legendDijit globally, then check to see if it is null. If not null, destroy it recursively, and recreate it. If null, create it.

```js
if (legendDijit) legendDijit.destroyRecursive();
legendDijit = new Legend({
   map: map,
   layerInfos: legendLayers
}, dojo.create('div', {}, "legend1"));
legendDijit.startup();
```